# Как вызвать программно JMenu?

Tags: java

Как вызвать программно `JMenu`?
Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялся `JMenu`

Comment: `setVisible(true)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно JMenu ты не засунешь в JButton. Однако есть способ с JPopupMenu. [Оригинал здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693326/5506820).

```
public class ToolbarDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    final JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();

    //Create the popup menu.
    final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Option 1") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Option 1 selected");
        }
    }));
    popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Option 2") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Option 2 selected");
        }
    }));

    final JButton button = new JButton("Options");
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());//при нажатии на кнопку всплывает меню 
        }
    });
    toolBar.add(button);

    frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

---

Comment: Хм, плохо что нельзя использовать обычный JMenu, но это понятно, главное что багов нету при вызове JPopupMenu ведь это окно)